# UISearchBar via UITableView with JSON

Tags: json, swift, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar

The `UISearchBar` cannot perform a search, what's wrong?

I am looking for no tutorial on searching using json, but my code is already displayed in the table view but cannot search. I am new to the iOS developer world.

```
import UIKit

class updatedata: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate{

   @IBOutlet weak var searchbarr: UISearchBar!
   private var actors : [listpeserta]! = []
   private var realdata : [listpeserta]! = []
   var searching = false
   
   @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       let url : URL = URL(string: "link")!
       var request : URLRequest = URLRequest (url: url)
       request.httpMethod = "GET"
       
       
       NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: .main) { (response, data, error) in
           guard let data = data else {
               print(error)
               return
           }
           let responseString : String! = String(data : data, encoding: .utf8)
           do {
               
               let jsonDecoder : JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()
               self.actors = try jsonDecoder.decode([listpeserta].self, from: data)
               self.realdata = self.actors
               self.tableView.reloadData()
           }catch{print(error.localizedDescription)}
       }
   }
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       if searching {return realdata.count}
       else
       { return actors.count}
   }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
       
       if searching {
       cell.textLabel?.text = realdata[indexPath.item].nama
       }else
       {cell.textLabel?.text = actors[indexPath.item].nama}
       
       return cell
    }
   
   
   func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
       realdata = actors.filter({$0.nama.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased()})
       searching = true
       tableView.reloadData()
   }
   func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
       searching = false
       searchBar.text = ""
       tableView.reloadData()
   }
     
}
```

this is, class listpeserta.swift

```
import Foundation

class listpeserta: Codable {
    public var nama : String!
}
```

Comment: Did you set the delegate of your searchBar searchbarr.delegate = self ? Didn't found one in your code or did I overlook it.

Comment: And also you said your code is already displayed in the table view, but I also can't find the tableview.dataSource = self. That make me a bit confused.

Comment: thankyuuu, searchbarr.delegate = self this is it

Comment: Alright glad to be of help, maybe I should post it as an answer then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem you're missing the delegate of the searchBar. Remember to add the delegate when you need to assign a task / responsibility to another object.

For example, inside your viewDidLoad:

```
searchbarr.delegate = self
```

p.s. tableView.dataSource = self is also missing.